# Why the context provider doesn't pass props with useContext inside children as function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the context props using `useContext` inside a children as function but the props are always the default

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext(undefined);

export default function Component() {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ variable: 123 }}>
      {(() => {
        const context_value = useContext(Context);
        console.log(context_value);
        return <></>;
      })()}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Output:

> undefined

I know I can use the `Context.Consumer` but in my real case is different because I'm creating a hook in another file to call `useContext(context)` instead of exporting `Context`

Comment: `useContext` hook must be used inside of a component body, but you are using it in a function callback, which is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use hooks (like `useContext`) at the top-level of function components (or in custom hooks), but not in the place where you're using it. Try to put a child component inside the provider and to put the `useContext` inside that child component.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, hope this will helpful to you also.

```
//AppContext.js
import { createContext } from 'react';
export const AppContext = createContext(null);


//Authenticated.js

import { useState } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from '@/src/AppContext';

export default function Authenticated()
{

 const [message, setMessage] = useState('message');

 return ( 
<AppContext.Provider value={{ message, setMessage }}>
   <FlashMessage />
</AppContext.Provider>
);

}


//FlashMessage.js
import { useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { AppContext } from '@/src/AppContext';

const export default FlashMessage = () =>
{
   const { message } = useContext(AppContext);

 return (
        <div>{message}</div>
    );
}
```